# Android bluetooth permission denial (although I use permissions)

Tags: android, bluetooth, permissions

To cut the story short. My logcat says:

> java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent {
>   act=android.bluetooth.adapter.action.REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE
>   cmp=com.android.settings/.bluetooth.RequestPermissionActivity (has
>   extras) }

While I'm trying to execute:

```
    Intent discoverIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
    discoverIntent.putExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION, 600);
    startActivity(discoverIntent);
```

I have included all required permissions in the manifest. Moreover, some time ago I have written another application using bluetooth, which includes exactly this code (and I'm using the same there permissions). In that app everything works properly, here I get this exception while executing startingActivity(discoverIntent).

Do you have any ideas what's going on?

**ANSWER ANSWER ANSWER**

Maybe it sounds silly, but after restarting(sic!) my mobile phone, everything works perfect and I don't get any exceptions. If you have problem like this, try this simple solution.

Comment: What version of Android are you testing this on?

Comment: Im using Android 4.3